# Remove all occurrences of unicode U+2009 in my document

Tags: unicode

I have .tex document into which "thinspace" was inserted, most likely while copying text from another document.

I am currently using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,}` to skip over this occurrence. Is it possible to search and delete this character from the document itself as it is not required.

I am using a Linux Mint 20.1, pdflatex and Texmaker as the frontend.

Comment: Do a search-and-replace in your editor, or [do it with PERL.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352623/unicode-char-u200b/548884#548884)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode char {U+200B}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352623/unicode-char-u200b)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to remove the character in any editor, but as you are on linux so probably have perl, you could use a commandline script:

```
perl -C -p -e 's/\x{2009}//g' file.tex > file-new.tex
```

will make a version of the file with all U+2009 removed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Unicode engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX) then you can set this character as ignored in TeX processing:

```
\catcode`\^^^^2009 = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are on linux, the good old Stream EDitor (sed)

```
sed -i 's/old-text/new-text/g' input.tex
```

or the more friendly to handle rpl

```
rpl "old-text" "new-text" --encoding UTF-8 -q input.tex
```

would be my choice if you have to do it on the command line.

for some more possible ways on linux have a look at [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272597)

otherwise, just use your text editor of choice.